# QueryException: could not resolve property: B.C of: A]

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, queryover

I have a query that goes something like this:

```
B BAlias = null;
C CAlias = null;

session.QueryOver<A>().Left.JoinAlias(x => x.B, () => BAlias).Left.JoinAlias(() => B.C, () => CAlias);


Query.Where(() => CAlias == C);

Query.And(() => BAlias.Id == Guid.Parse(SearchColumn));

Query.And(x => x.SomeData == data_string);


return Query.OrderBy(() => B.Name).Desc
                                .Skip(skip)
                                .Take(take)
                                .List<A>();
```

Essentially, I need to load a list of A objects that has the indirect property of C, via B. (Hope this doesn't sound too confusing)

I can't get it to work, getting errors all over for such 'sub-sub query', any ideas how this may be coded to work?

**EDIT:**

Added the order by query.

Error comes in the form of:

could not resolve property: B.C of: A

**EDIT 2:**

Mappings as below:

```
public void Override(AutoMapping<A> mapping)
    {
        mapping.References<B>(x => x.B).Not.Nullable().Not.LazyLoad();
    }

public void Override(AutoMapping<B> mapping)
    {
        mapping.References(x => x.C).Not.Nullable().Cascade.SaveUpdate();
    }

public void Override(AutoMapping<C> mapping)
    {
        mapping.Map(x => x.Name).CustomSqlType("VARCHAR(255)").Not.Nullable().Unique();
    }


public class A: BaseEntity<A>
{

    public virtual B B{ get; set; }
    public virtual string SomeData{ get; set; }
}


public class B: BaseEntity<B>
{

    public virtual C C{ get; set; }
    public virtual string Name{ get; set; }
}

public class C: BaseEntity<C>
{
    public virtual string Name{ get; set; }
    public virtual string Description{ get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Is'nt `C` a type? I think the problem is in your `Query.Where(() => CAlias == C)`

Comment: Can you post your mappings for A, B and C ta

Comment: pls have a look on my edits..

Answer (score 0):

Use `JoinQueryOver`.

The error means that you're using `B.C` as if it was a property name, but it's not. `JoinQueryOver` enables you to query by a property of a property.

Comment: @IIya Kogan, however I need to be get a list of A objects, I dont see how I can do so with JoinQueryOver/

Comment: Why not? This is exactly what JoinQueryOver exists for.

Comment: Ahh. I see where this is going. Forgot to mention, that I do need to do some filtering on A and B..

Answer (score 0):

`B.C` should probably be `BAlias.C`